# Custom sort between two values

Tags: javascript

if the array is something like:

```
const arr = 
  [ { level: 'mid'    }
  , { level: 'senior' }
  , { level: 'junior' }
  , { level: 'senior' }
  , { level: 'mid'    }
  , { level: 'junior' }
  , { level: 'entry'  }
  ];
```

how can i sort `levels:'senior'` always below `junior” no matter what?

i tried the standard sort code where `senior` always comes last, but it should always be sorted after `junior`.

this is the code i tried:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.level===’senior’)-(b.level===‘senior’)
)}
```

expected result:
*the senior object should be automatically sorted after the last junior object.*

```
[ { level: 'mid'    }
, { level: 'junior' }
, { level: 'mid'    }
, { level: 'junior' }
, { level: 'senior' }
, { level: 'senior' }
, { level: 'entry'  } 
];
```

Comment: Should junior and senior be the last 2 values and the rest of the elements stay as is? Or the rest of the elements order does not matter?

Comment: it's okay if the order of the other values change depending on the sort. just that senior should always be sorted below junior...but it shouldnt be sorted at the end of the list

Comment: Check out the answer.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: expected result: arr = [ { 'level' : 'mid' }, { 'level' : ‘junior’ }, { 'level' : 'mid' }, { 'level' : 'junior' }, { 'level' : ‘senior’ },{ 'level' : ‘senior’ }, { 'level' : ‘entry’ } ];

Comment: the senior object should be automatically sorted after the last junior object.

Comment: It's not a _sort_, it's a **rearrangement**, even if it was a _selective sort,_ then `entry` should be the first item

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting like this

```
function sortArray() {
  var arr = [{ 'level': 'mid' }, { 'level': 'senior' }, { 'level': 'junior' }, { 'level': 'senior' }, { 'level': 'mid' }, { 'level': 'junior' }, { 'level': 'entry' }];
    
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => (a.level > b.level) ? 1 : -1)
    
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: i only want the array to be sorted based on the junior or senior values. can i do a custom sort so that objects with other values don't get affected?

Comment: do you mean you need only junior and senior level. You don't need entry and mid.

Comment: no. i want the "entry" and "mid" to stay in the array as it is. the sort should only happen between junior and senior.

Comment: please share the expected output also in question. Also, accept the modification as the given array had issues.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a custom sort function where:

1. All of your non **junior/senior** levels are moved upfront. (This does a partition in your array )
2. You specifically handle the case of **junior** and **senior**.

```js
let arr = [{ 'level' : 'mid' },{'level' : 'senior' }, { 'level' : 'junior' }, { 'level' : 'senior' }, { 'level' : 'mid' }, { 'level' : 'junior' }, { 'level' : 'entry' }];

arr.sort((a, b) => {  if(['mid','entry'].indexOf(b.level) > -1) return 1;

else if(b.level === 'junior' && a.level === 'senior') return 1;

return -1;
});
 
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr.level` is a string. Use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort on strings:

```js
const levelSortAscending = (a, b) => a.level.localeCompare(b.level);
const levelSortDescending = (a, b) => b.level.localeCompare(a.level);
const arr = [
  { 'level' : 'mid' },
  { 'level' : 'senior' }, 
  { 'level' : 'junior' }, 
  { 'level' : 'senior' }, 
  { 'level' : 'mid' },
  { 'level' : 'junior' },
  { 'level' : 'entry' } ]
  .sort( levelSortAscending );
  
document.querySelector('pre').textContent = `---ascending---\n${
  JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)}`;
document.querySelector('pre').textContent += `\n\n---descending---\n${
  JSON.stringify(arr.sort( levelSortDescending ), null, 2)}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

But you don't want to *sort* the array. Cf your comment you want to *reshuffle* it. So:

```js
const arr = [
  { 'level' : 'mid' }, { 'level' : 'senior' }, { 'level' : 'junior' }, 
  { 'level' : 'senior' }, { 'level' : 'mid' }, { 'level' : 'junior' },
  { 'level' : 'entry' } ];
  
const intermediate = arr.reduce( (acc, val) => 
  val.level !== 'senior' ? [...acc, val] : acc , []);
const lastJunior = intermediate.map(v => v.level).lastIndexOf('junior');
const seniors = arr.filter(v => v.level === 'senior');
const finalArr = [
    ...intermediate.slice(0, lastJunior + 1), 
    ...seniors, 
    ...intermediate.slice(lastJunior + 1) ];

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(finalArr, null, 2);

// shorter alternative
const [seniorLevels, reshuffled] = arr.reduce( (acc, val) =>
  acc[val.level === 'senior' ? 0 : 1].push(val) && acc, [[], []]);

// reinsert
reshuffled.splice(
  reshuffled.map(v => v.level).lastIndexOf('junior') + 1,
  0, 
  ...seniorLevels);
document.querySelector('pre').textContent += `\n\nResult of alternative\n${
  JSON.stringify(reshuffled, null, 2)}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate from the end and check if the wanted item is found after you want to insert an iten.

```js
const
    array = [{ level: 'mid' }, { level: 'senior', x: 1 }, { level: 'junior' }, { level: 'senior', x: 2 }, { level: 'mid' }, { level: 'junior' }, { level: 'entry' }],
    item = 'senior',
    after = 'junior',
    result = array.reduceRight((offset => (r, o, i, a) => {
        if (offset === -1 && o.level === after) offset = a.length - 1 - i;
        if (offset !== -1 && o.level === item) r.splice(r.length - offset++, 0, o);
        else r.unshift(o);
        return r;
    })(-1), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```